# Copy file to destination based on ini file

Tags: bash, command-line, osx, cp

I have a few thousand subdirectories in a directory, each containing one `config.ini` file and one JPEG image. The ini file contains (including but not limited to) a section that encodes the time, when the image was taken.

```
[Acquisition]
Name=coating_filtered_001
Comment=Image acquisition
Year=2017
Month=3
Day=21
Hour=13
Minute=2
Second=34
Milliseconds=567
```

The image files always have the same exact name, for the sake of this question `image.jpg`.

I would like to copy all image files to some other (single) directory, and rename them to something like `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss:NNN.jpg` or similar, i.e. the filename consisting of the timestamp from the ini file.

Can this be achieved on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *can* be achieved on the command line, but a script that would run on the command line would be an easier solution (I think).

Basic steps:

- Get a list of directories to iterate over:
  `find ${directory} -mindepth 1 -type d`
- Check each directory for the presence of `config.ini`, and `image.jpg`.
  `if [ -f ${subdir}/config.ini -a -f ${subdir}/image.jpg ]; then ...`
- Check the config.ini for all the right parts of the timestamp.
  various `grep ^Year= ${subdir}/config.ini` or `^Month`, etc...
- Make a copy of the image.jpg file, using the timestamp.
  `cp ${subdir}/image.jpg ${copydir}/${timestamp}.jpg`

I think it's easier, and potentially safer to put these sequences into a script, where you can more easily put in readable output, error handling, etc.

Here's an example script to do those steps:

```
#!/bin/bash

imagepath="/path/to/images"
copydir="/path/to/copies"

# step 1: find all the directories
for dir in $(find ${imagepath} -mindepth 1 -type d); do
    echo "Procesing directory $dir:"
    ci=${dir}/config.ini
    jp=${dir}/image.jpg

    # step 2: check for config.ini and image.jpg
    if [ -f ${ci} -a -f ${jp} ]; then
        # step 3: get the parts of the timestamp
        year=$(grep ^Year= ${ci}   | cut -d= -f2)
        month=$(grep ^Month= ${ci} | cut -d= -f2)
        day=$(grep ^Day= ${ci}     | cut -d= -f2)
        hour=$(grep ^Hour= ${ci}   | cut -d= -f2)
        min=$(grep ^Minute= ${ci}  | cut -d= -f2)
        sec=$(grep ^Second= ${ci}  | cut -d= -f2)
        ms=$(grep ^Milliseconds= ${ci} | cut -d= -f2)

        # if any timestamp part is empty, don't copy the file
        # instead, write a note, and we can check it manually
        if [[ -z ${year} || -z ${month} || -z ${day} || -z ${hour} || -z ${min} || -z ${sec} || -z ${ms} ]]; then
            echo "Date variables not as expected in ${ci}!"
        else
            # step 4: copy file
            # if we got here, all the files are there, and the config.ini
            # had all the timestamp parts.
            tsfile="${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${min}:${sec}:${ms}.jpg"
            target="${copydir}/${tsfile}"
            echo -n "Archiving ${jp} to ${target}: "
            st=$(cp ${jp} ${target} 2>&1)
            # capture the status and alert if there's an error
            if (( $? == 0 )); then
                echo "[ ok ]"
            else
                echo "[ err ]"
            fi
            [ ! -z $st ] && echo $st
        fi
    else
        # other side of step2... some file is missing... 
        # manual check recommended, no action taken
        echo "No config.ini or image.jpeg in ${dir}!"
    fi
    echo "---------------------"
done
```

It's always good to be somewhat conservative with scripts like this, so you don't accidentally delete files.  This script only does 1 copy action, so that's pretty conservative, and it shouldn't harm your source files.  But you may want to change specific actions or output messages to better suit your needs.

Comment: This did work as intended. I realized, my ini-files had windows line-endings, so I had to pipe them through `dos2unix` before using your script. Otherwise `cut` would include the `\r` character in the file names.

Comment: in the pipline between `grep` and `cut`, you can add a `| tr -d '\r' |`, to save you the extra step.

Answer (score 0):

```
top="$(pwd -P)" \
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
   shift "$1"
   for iDir
   do
      cd "$iDir" && \
      if [ -f "image.jpg" ] && [ -s "config.ini" ]; then
         eval "$(sed -e "/^[[]Acquisition]/,/^Milliseconds/!d
                  /^Year=/b; /^Month=/b; /^Day=/b; /^Hour=/b; /^Minute=/b
                  /^Second=/b; /^Milliseconds=/b; d" config.ini)"
         new=$(printf "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d\n" \
                  "$Year" "$Month" "$Day" "$Hour" "$Minute" "$Second" "$Milliseconds")
         echo cp -p "image.jpg" "$new"
         cp -p "image.jpg" "$new"
      else
        #echo >&2 "$iDir/image.jpg &/or config.ini file(s) missing or empty."
        :
      fi
      cd "$top"
   done
' 2 1 {} +

#meth-2
find . -type f -name config.ini -exec perl -F= -lane '
    push @A, $F[1] if /^\[Acquisition]/ .. /^Milliseconds/ and
                     /^(?:Year|Month|Day|Hour|Minute|Second|Milliseconds)=/;
    next if ! eof;
    my(@a, $fmt) = qw/-  -  T  :  :  :/;
    (my $d = $ARGV) =~ s|/[^/]+$||;
    print( STDERR "No image.jpg in dir: $d"),next if ! -f $d . "/image.jpg";
    $fmt .= "${_}$a[$a++]" for map { "%0${_}s" } qw/4 2 2 2 2 2 3/;
    print for map { "$d/$_" } "image.jpg", sprintf "$fmt.jpg", @A;
    ($a,@A)=(0);
' {} + | xargs -n 2 echo mv
```